Keycloak: Duplicate role names listed in JWT token
tried to access the authorization server and obtained the JWT token. When I decoded the token using jq, I noticed that the roles under the 'roles' section are duplicated. How can I remove the duplicated roles?
{
    "aud": [
        "security-admin-console",
        "Test-management"
    ],
    "resource_access": {
        "realm-management": {
            "roles": [
                "view-Test",
                "Test-admin",
                "query-Test",
                "manage-Test"
            ]
        },
        "Test": {
            "roles": [
                "Test-user"
            ]
        },
        "account": {
            "roles": [
                "test-role"
            ]
        },
        "Data": {
            "roles": [
                "data-user"
            ]
        }
    },
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "sid": "",
    "email_verified": false,
    "org": "Test",
    "roles": [
        "view-Test",
        "Test-admin",
        "query-Test",
        "manage-Test",
        "Test-user",
        "test-role",
        "data-user",
        "view-Test",
        "Test-admin",
        "query-Test",
        "manage-Test",
        "Test-user",
        "test-role",
        "data-user",
        "view-Test",
        "Test-admin",
        "query-Test",
        "manage-Test",
        "Test-user",
        "test-role",
        "data-user"
    ],
    "groups": [
        "Administrators",
        "Users"
    ],
    "preferred_username": "TestUser"
}

Expected:
{
    "aud": [
        "security-admin-console",
        "Test-management"
    ],
    "resource_access": {
        "realm-management": {
            "roles": [
                "view-Test",
                "Test-admin",
                "query-Test",
                "manage-Test"
            ]
        },
        "Test": {
            "roles": [
                "Test-user"
            ]
        },
        "account": {
            "roles": [
                "test-role"
            ]
        },
        "Data": {
            "roles": [
                "data-user"
            ]
        }
    },
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "sid": "",
    "email_verified": false,
    "org": "Test",
    "roles": [
        "view-Test",
        "Test-admin",
        "query-Test",
        "manage-Test",
        "Test-user",
        "test-role",
        "data-user"
    ],
    "groups": [
        "Administrators",
        "Users"
    ],
    "preferred_username": "TestUser"
}

sample KeycloakRealmImport yaml file :
test-realm-import.yaml
apiVersion: keycloak.org/v1alpha1
kind: KeycloakRealmImport
metadata:
  name: test-realm-import
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  realm: Test
  enabled: true
  users:
    - username: TestUser
      emailVerified: false
      email: testuser@example.com
      firstName: Test
      lastName: User
      groups:
        - Administrators
        - Users
      clientRoles:
        security-admin-console:
          - view-Test
          - Test-admin
          - query-Test
          - manage-Test
        Test:
          - Test-user
        account:
          - test-role
        Data:
          - data-user
      realmRoles:
        - view-Test
        - Test-admin
        - query-Test
        - manage-Test
        - Test-user
        - test-role
        - data-user
      attributes:
        aud:
          - security-admin-console
          - Test-management
        scope:
          - openid
          - profile
          - email
      preferredUsername: TestUser
  roles:
    - name: view-Test
      description: View access to Test resources
    - name: Test-admin
      description: Admin access to Test resources
    - name: query-Test
      description: Query access to Test resources
    - name: manage-Test
      description: Manage access to Test resources
    - name: Test-user
      description: User access to Test resources
    - name: test-role
      description: Basic user role
    - name: data-user
      description: Access to Data resources
  groups:
    - name: Administrators
      realmRoles:
        - view-Test
        - Test-admin
        - query-Test
        - manage-Test
    - name: Users
      realmRoles:
        - Test-user
        - data-user


{"exp": ,"iat": ,"auth_time": ,... isn't valid json. Can you post what you actually got (with redacted values is appropriate)?

@Holloway updated the json. Sorry Im not able to the exact values.

Your JSON still invalid, you can check in here, And you need to share how to use jq with get token API.

@BenchVue . updated the json.   Jq usage like "echo "<jwt_token> | cut -d '.' -f 2 | base64 --decode | jq ."

Test JWT
token.jwt
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsic2VjdXJpdHktYWRtaW4tY29uc29sZSIsIlRlc3QtbWFuYWdlbWVudCJdLCJyZXNvdXJjZV9hY2Nlc3MiOnsicmVhbG0tbWFuYWdlbWVudCI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJ2aWV3LVRlc3QiLCJUZXN0LWFkbWluIiwicXVlcnktVGVzdCIsIm1hbmFnZS1UZXN0Il19LCJUZXN0Ijp7InJvbGVzIjpbIlRlc3QtdXNlciJdfSwiYWNjb3VudCI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJ0ZXN0LXJvbGUiXX0sIkRhdGEiOnsicm9sZXMiOlsiZGF0YS11c2VyIl19fSwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCIsInNpZCI6IiIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwib3JnIjoiVGVzdCIsInJvbGVzIjpbInZpZXctVGVzdCIsIlRlc3QtYWRtaW4iLCJxdWVyeS1UZXN0IiwibWFuYWdlLVRlc3QiLCJUZXN0LXVzZXIiLCJ0ZXN0LXJvbGUiLCJkYXRhLXVzZXIiLCJ2aWV3LVRlc3QiLCJUZXN0LWFkbWluIiwicXVlcnktVGVzdCIsIm1hbmFnZS1UZXN0IiwiVGVzdC11c2VyIiwidGVzdC1yb2xlIiwiZGF0YS11c2VyIiwidmlldy1UZXN0IiwiVGVzdC1hZG1pbiIsInF1ZXJ5LVRlc3QiLCJtYW5hZ2UtVGVzdCIsIlRlc3QtdXNlciIsInRlc3Qtcm9sZSIsImRhdGEtdXNlciJdLCJncm91cHMiOlsiQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcnMiLCJVc2VycyJdLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJUZXN0VXNlciIsImlhdCI6MTczMzg1MzA0Mn0.yTHHN3Ypm2bQXkgvVKL_z0GiouyeICnus-UmszFgn2c

Save jq-data.json from your jq commend
cat token.jwt | awk -F. '{print $2}' | sed 's/-/+/g; s/_/\//g; s/=$//g' | base64 -d | jq > jq-data.json

jq-data.json
{
  "aud": [
    "security-admin-console",
    "Test-management"
  ],
  "resource_access": {
    "realm-management": {
      "roles": [
        "view-Test",
        "Test-admin",
        "query-Test",
        "manage-Test"
      ]
    },
    "Test": {
      "roles": [
        "Test-user"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "test-role"
      ]
    },
    "Data": {
      "roles": [
        "data-user"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "sid": "",
  "email_verified": false,
  "org": "Test",
  "roles": [
    "view-Test",
    "Test-admin",
    "query-Test",
    "manage-Test",
    "Test-user",
    "test-role",
    "data-user",
    "view-Test",
    "Test-admin",
    "query-Test",
    "manage-Test",
    "Test-user",
    "test-role",
    "data-user",
    "view-Test",
    "Test-admin",
    "query-Test",
    "manage-Test",
    "Test-user",
    "test-role",
    "data-user"
  ],
  "groups": [
    "Administrators",
    "Users"
  ],
  "preferred_username": "TestUser",
  "iat": 1733853042
}

Run this jq commend to remove duplicate role
jq '.roles |= (unique | sort)' jq-data.json > updated-jq-data.json

updated-jq-data.json
{
  "aud": [
    "security-admin-console",
    "Test-management"
  ],
  "resource_access": {
    "realm-management": {
      "roles": [
        "view-Test",
        "Test-admin",
        "query-Test",
        "manage-Test"
      ]
    },
    "Test": {
      "roles": [
        "Test-user"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "test-role"
      ]
    },
    "Data": {
      "roles": [
        "data-user"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "sid": "",
  "email_verified": false,
  "org": "Test",
  "roles": [
    "Test-admin",
    "Test-user",
    "data-user",
    "manage-Test",
    "query-Test",
    "test-role",
    "view-Test"
  ],
  "groups": [
    "Administrators",
    "Users"
  ],
  "preferred_username": "TestUser",
  "iat": 1733853042
}

You directly save the updated JSON into a file updated-jq-data.json without first saving it as jq-data.json.
cat token.jwt | awk -F. '{print $2}' | sed 's/-/+/g; s/_/\//g; s/=$//g' | base64 -d | jq '.roles |= (unique | sort)' > updated-jq-data.json


Thank  you for sharing the solution. but why the roles are duplicating.

I don’t know never seen before how to reproduce it?

"Keycloak is deployed along with KeycloakRealmImport, and the Keycloak database is also set up. All configurations for realms, clients, users, and roles are specified using KeycloakRealmImport.
This is the procedure i followed.

Do you have url to follow your steps? I can try it

https://www.keycloak.org/operator/realm-import   https://www.keycloak.org/operator/installation

I checked that URL it just install operator there are no import realm step.

we can define roles, groups, client and all mappings in KeycloakRealmImport .
